# I need help with this congruence. What will be the approach to the solution? (From George E. Andrews book)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

From the book Number Theory by George. E. Andrews page 52

$n^2 \equiv -1$ (mod $p$)

Where $p$ is a prime. Characterize the primes for which this congruence has a solution.

Comment: This is known as the 1st supplement of the law of quadratic reciprocity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#The_supplementary_laws_using_Legendre_symbols

Comment: Have you tried solving this for any particular primes? Try for about 5 or 6 primes and you may notice a pattern. It would be helpful in writing an answer if you could tell us what you know and what you've tried.

Comment: You will find more about this in chapter 9

Comment: One thing you should *always* do when faced with a problem like this, especially if you don't know how else to start, is to work out a bunch of (small) examples and see if you can detect a pattern for yourself.  This won't necessarily give you the answer (much less a proof), but it will give you a feel for the problem.  And if nothing else, it gives you something to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll find later in the book this deals with quadratic residues. But to just get a heuristic feel for the problem, try it for different primes. e.g. 
$n^2\equiv -1 \pmod5$ has a solution $(n=2,3)$, and so does $n^2\equiv -1 \pmod{13}$       ($n=5,8)$, however no solutions exist for $3,11$ or $7$. What characterizes them?

Note that for every prime with a solution $\frac{p-1}2$ is even, or equivalently $$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv1 \pmod p$$
Has solutions precisely when $p$ satisfies $n^2\equiv -1 \pmod p$, or in other words when $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$. You can see Andrews' full proof of this, known as Euler's Criterion, on page 116.

Comment: That's very nice. I tried a couple of primes 3 and 5 but never thought about searching for a pattern after trying different prime numbers. I will try this approach. I should also thanks everyone else for their inputs. Also, let me tell you this community is so great, to have collaboration within seconds of posting my question is a very precious thing.